# How to stop retry mechanism in slack bot chat_postmessage slackbolt

Tags: python, slack-api, slack-bolt

Developed a slack bot using Python to auto reply to the messages that are posted in slack channel. Bot is sometimes replying twice with same reply message.

`app.client.chat_postMessage(channel=message.get("channel"), thread_ts=message_posted.get("ts"), text="Ack the message",blocks=blocks)`.

Its purely an intermittent issue and hope it's failing to call API for 1st time and during retry its getting posted twice. So need help on below two -

How to store logs in logger in a log file and delete the data in a file, line by line if log file size exceeds 1GB?

Code to disable retry mechanism for chat_postmessage. If it fails wait for 1min and then retry it again if the bot has not replied? (In-bulit retry mechanism, wait for only 3sec before the next retry is what I read so want to manually try it having high wait time). Know that we need to pass X-Slack-No-Retry: 1 as header, but not sure how to pass it correctly. So code would be appreciated. TIA :)